# Как обращаться из одного скрипта в другой с помощью переменных без потери информации о ней в unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Доброго времени суток!

Я соединил два скрипта с помощью переменных.

В первом скрипте: `[SerializeField] public static float crystalCounter = 0;`

И во втором: `Spawner.crystalCounter -= 1;`

Второй скрипт изменяет значение crystalCounter на -1.

Так вот `[SerializeField]` перестал работать из-за `public static` и в Unity не отображается!
[image: Не отображается crystalCounter]

На что можно заменить `public static` ?

Comment: Статичные поля принадлежат классу, а не объекту
В вашей ситуации можно использовать: [Singelton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фух, мой звёздный час.
Пока ты новичок в программировании, вообще не советую использовать модификатор static и паттерн Singleton.
Вместо этого пиши следующим образом:

```
public float crystalCounter = 0;
```

Это всё ещё не лучший вариант, потому-что безопаснее использовать свойства, но о них узнаешь позже.
Затем в классе Spawner объяви поле типа( то есть названия класса) первого скрипта.

```
[SerializeField] private ScriptName _scriptName;
```

В инспекторе перенеси объект, в котором находится первый скрипт прямо в это поле(так же, как ты делал с Crystal).
И.... вуаля, теперь ты можешь использовать все доступные методы и поля другого класса, и тебе не придётся в дальнейшем страдать из-за модификатора static.

```
_scriptName.crystalCounter -= 1;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Лучший)